# Basic Multivariable Calculus Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My friend is studying for a calculus exam by solving previous exams. He asked me about a question which states:

Show that :
 $$\int_{0}^{x} [\int_{0}^{v}[\int_{0}^{u}dt]du]dv = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{x} (x - t^2)f(t)dt$$

It doesn't state anything about $f$, and I think there must be a typo, but I'm here asking for a second opinion. I tried solving an ODE for $f$ - but this mustn't be the case, as ODEs are taught further away in the subject. Does anyone have an opinion for this question?

Comment: Haven't tried solving the question. But I'm thinking it could mean that $f (t) $ stands for "other terms which involve $t $".  Not any function in particular

Comment: Don't you find It a bit strange that a variable is both the limit of integration and a part of the integrand? I tried solving this in a purely formal way, but still, couldn't figure how to do it.